# Can't find assemblies specified

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, .net-assembly, dynamics-crm-4

I'm on CRM 4.0 and I get the following error when I try to execute retrieval of multiple entities.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I'm pretty sure that the assembly referred is *microsoft.crm.sdktypeproxy* because the other one (*microsoft.crm.sdk*) is doesn't create any issues.

So I went to the server and added the former at each location where the latter resides. To no avail. I need the assembly because I'll be retrieving multiples instances of custom entities.

I copied the DLLs to *CRMWeb\bin* and *Server\bin* as well as my plugin registration tool directory and in IIS at a few places. How can I trouble-shoot this one?!

Comment: let's see the entire stacktrace.

Comment: after you copied did you issue an iis-reset?

Comment: @TMcKeown what would a stack trace tell you for this one?

Comment: curious where this is occuring, firing from within crm or within a specific dll.. It's helpful to me.

Comment: which .NET version are you targeting? If it's CRM 4.0 use .NET 3.5, not .NET 4.0

Comment: Is this for Plugin code or some ASP.NET code deployed to the ISV folder?

Comment: @TMcKeown I'm not allowed to turn on logging. The client has no test environment. We're working in dev. However, as far I can see, it fires from the DLL I'm deploing when it tries to use *microsoft.crm.sdktypeproxy*.

Comment: @GuidoPreite I'm targeting .NET 4.0 or .NET 4.5. And, since it's CRM 4.0, you might be onto something. I'll try that tomorrow. However, .NET 4.0 is installed on the server **and** we're using features from it as well so I hope you're wrong...   :)   Are you talking out of experience or do you know of a place where this limitation is documented? Why can't I use .NET 4.0?

Comment: @Nicknow Plugin. No ISV.

Comment: @KonradViltersten because it's a plugin I'm quite sure it will be executed using the .net version of CRM 4.0 application pool, and CRM 4.0 doesn't support .NET 4.0.

Comment: Okay, I think @GuidoPreite has found the culprit (feel free to copy this to an answer so you can get the credit.)

CRM 4 plugins run in the context of the Dynamics CRM 4 application. Dynamics CRM 4 is a .NET 3.0 application. Therefore, for a plugin to run in Dynamics 4 it must target a .NET 3.0 compatible framework, which .NET 4 is not. This is why you get the error on System.Core - no access to System.Core 4.0.

I'm not sure where exactly it is written in the CRM 4 SDK but here is a post from the CRM product team that clearly states plugins should target .NET 3.0: http://goo.gl/kD17GH.

Comment: @Nicknow you are right, but I found also that CRM 4.0 rollup 18 introduced the support for .net 4.0, I added the answer with the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error refers to a .NET 4.0 assembly, probably your Dynamics CRM 4.0 environment has not been updated to (at least) rollup 18, the minimum rollup that support .NET 4.0, as stated here:

[Microsoft Dynamics CRM Compatibility List](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669061)

If the CRM has a lower rollup it supports only .NET 3.0/.NET 3.5

Comment: Funny (read: terribly unfunny) story. At my client's, they decided not to install the latest RU. In fact, they've **never** installed a roll-up. So, be that RU18 or RU-anything-else. I'm birded... (Read: I'm ducked, but with "w".) You're godlike, Guido!

Answer (score 1):

The tool to use for troubleshooting is [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).  If any of the assemblies referenced are native 32bit or 64bit, make sure your application is set to match - that is a common cause of this exception.